# Odoo 13 How to edit field with Html widget from code?

Tags: xml, field, odoo, odoo-13, odoo-view

I have field for description:

```
test_field = fields.Char(string='Test')
```

in XML form it looks like this:

```
<field name="test_field" widget="html" />
```

The question is How can I insert table row with some value from code to this field?

I tried to write html markup as a text like this:

[image]

but it wraps as paragraph and displays as ordinary text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your field definition should be as following:

```py
test_field = fields.Html(string='Test')
```